# relation from a to b would cause an invalid circular inheritance/realization combination

Tags: rational-rose

I get this error and I search for it more times but I don't find any causes for it. if I create 2 Use Case without noting, when I link them in 1 direction they link with generalization but when I delete (delete from model) link and draw link in opposite direction it create that error. some reason I found in google but they are not correct for me (delete from model or circular inheritance in not valid) in this case.help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this solved my problem:
- recover the mistake relation, right click it, and choose "Delete from Model" will solve your problem
- Ctrl + D